# How to update Imageview(android data binding) after getting response from retrofit

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

following is the layout file:
 I'm using custom setter i.e BindingAdapter

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8dp"
        bind:pic="@{item.deviceType}"
        bind:status="@{item.deviceStatus}"
        />
```

the pic will get int value which biphergate the device
the status is boolean value.

this is my bindingadpter:

```
 @BindingAdapter(value = {"bind:status","bind:pic"},requireAll = false)
public static void setImage(ImageView imageview,boolean status,int type){

    if(Integer.valueOf(type)==257){
        if(status)
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lightbulb_on);
        else
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lightbulb);

    }else if(Integer.valueOf(type)==516){
        if(status)
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_open_door);
        else
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_closed_door);
    }
}
```

now I am getting the response from retrofit after the execution of binding adapter, so how can I notify the binding that I've data and update the view and call binding adapter again?

Comment: Please state more clearly what you are trying to achieve. Are deviceType and deviceStatus being fetched from the server? You called your binding adapter attributes `bind:status` and `bind:pic` but in the ImageView you are using `app:status` and `app:pic` - this is wrong. You should change `bind:status` and `bind:pic` to `status` and `pic`

Comment: @Wess yes it fetches from cloud

Comment: Why didn't you use `type == 257` instead of `Integer.valueOf(type)==257`?

Comment: Okay. If the server returns with deviceType and deviceStatus then you should just do `yourViewModel.setDeviceType()` and `yourViewModel.setDeviceStatus()`. Databinding will then call your BindingAdapter method automatically (if you fixed `"bind:status"` to `"status"` and `"bind:pic"` to `"pic"`). I'm thinking your only problem is the attributes that you named incorrectly.

Comment: @Wess data binding already calling my method and i also changed app to bind but it won't update it when the resonse arrives

Comment: @Urvishrana please update your question with your view model class code and a code snippet where you are receiving the callback from server and setting values on the view model. I can't help you further without more information.

Comment: Also, using `bind:pic` and `bind:status` in your layout is bad practice if you're not using it to bind variables to an `<include/>` layout - [see this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#includes). You should use the `app:` namespace in your layout when referring to a user defined unique BindingAdapter attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after many hours I found out solutions
you just need to add

```
notifyChange();
```

after you get the response from API.